# Kubernetes cluster down

Tags: kubernetes

When running following command for cluster down in Kubernetes, I am getting following error:

> KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-down.sh
>
> rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/kubelet/pods/16981b98-a3bb-11e5-99fb-00505622b20d/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-0i2n6’: Device or resource busy

I tried to remove it forcefully but then also its not getting removed.

Comment: Are you running this command with sufficient privilege ?

Comment: I've seen similar things in Docker >= 1.9. I think it's a bug.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/17145

Answer (score 1):

I think this was fixed by https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/17315
You might want to check if you have the latest `cluster/ubuntu/*` files.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're wondering what the underlying mechanics of such an error are, seeing a `Device or resource busy` typically means there's a kernel-held "lock" on something at that point in the file system and the operation for [`unlink`-ing](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) (that is the [syscall](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operating-system-introduction-system-call/) that the `rm` command uses to request this action from the kernel) and is prevented, with an error condition (EBUSY).   You can learn a lot more about what syscalls are used by running a command through [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) if you want to see all syscalls involved (including the return codes from syscall invocations).

That path looks to me where kubelet manages pod-specific "filesystem-esque" parameters, in this case, what is happening is that every namespace has a default service account that then gets a default token, and that token is transparently mounted inside the pod container's file system.  That path mentioned in the error, is the host-level filesystem location of the pod's "internal" filesystem.  So in this case, the "lock" in question is a mount-point.

Basically that script is trying to removing that path (perhaps clean-up after itself) and it's still in-use (perhaps the pod was still running), and the script or some command it's invoking is not doing proper error-checking/handling, so you end up seeing that error instead.